# Remastersys does not work

Tags: 16.04, remastersys

Here's the deal. I want to create a custom Ubuntu distro, but I can't. I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and used Remastersys to make an ISO with it, and it doesn't work.

Here's what happens. I set up all of the correct settings, click on the ISO, and then it starts building. After that, a menu appears. There's only 2 options although I'm aware that there's supposed to be 3. The first one says to open the console application, and the second one says to continue building.

I wanted to customize it, so I clicked "Open Console Application". Then it doesn't open, and I get the following error:

```
Option "-t" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I've searched all over the internet, and couldn't find a solution. Does anybody here know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remastersys has  been abandoned for years. You'll need to use the manual method from [Rinzwind's answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/49679/158442).

Answer (score 1):

Pinguy Builder is a simple, yet useful application to backup or remix an installed Ubuntu operating system. It is the fork of Remastersys tool which is abandoned years ago. Pinguy Builder allows us either to easily backup the entire Ubuntu system or just create an installable ISO of the running system. Then, you can burn the ISO to any DVD or USB, and install that OS on any system. http://www.ostechnix.com/pinguy-builder-build-custom-ubuntu-os/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.